# Why do my CSS modules parents inherit properties of children?

Tags: css-modules, react-css-modules

I have the following syntax (JSX):

```
  <div ref={setNodeRef} style={style} className={`${styles.section} ${className} col-md-12`}>
    <div className={`${styles.green}`}></div>
  </div>
```

And in my `file.module.css`, the following CSS:

```
.section {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.green {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px green solid;
}
```

It seems that `.section` inherits `.green`'s properties even if the two have nothing to do with each other. How could this be?

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this case was me generating class names in a non-unique way. Since I'm using CSS Modules, I played around with some stuff and messed up the `localIdentName` variable in my `webpack.js` configuration.

Setting it up as:

```
localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
```

Made it work again since classes are now unique.